# Manage Passwords between multiple individuals

Tags: security, account-management, passwords

My co-workers and I frequently share passwords for many different online services.  We are constantly emailing each other passwords and resetting them because of the difficulty in locating the old ones.

Is there a way we can share and manage passwords securely and efficiently that will work for multiple people?

I came across [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/482/is-there-a-safe-way-to-save-passwords) answer which I really liked. However, I don't see it working between multiple individuals.  Many of us already have personal drop-boxes and it isn't realistic to switch back and forth to synchronise new passwords.

Answer (score 5):

Use [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) and use a single KeePass DB (kdb file) stored on a shared drive or in a [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/). Store all your passwords in that databse and they can all access it.

Comment: You can also share a folder within Dropbox to your colleagues so they don't need to run 2 dropbox accounts.

Comment: I use KeePass/Dropbox for personal and it works awesome. I've implemented KeePass a few times in an IT department and works great  most of the time. Where it fails is that it's a single write application so if someone else has it locked you can't save changes.

Comment: @citadelgrad Yeah, we have the same issue here, but it is not a serious problem since for the vast majority of the time it is being used as a reference. If someone has to write everyone else just has to release it.

Answer (score 1):

We use a shared file on a network drive (Notepad, Excel, etc).  You can use a cryptography app to keep the whole file under a password as well.  While Google Docs is probably OK, I would keep this particular type file off the web if possible.

Answer (score 1):

We use [**PassPack**](http://www.passpack.com/en/products/?ref=home|home|btsplash) to share passwords in our IT department. PassPack allows you to share passwords between different users. You can used the online version or the installable AIR [application](http://blog.passpack.com/2010/01/new-passpack-desktop-release/) so you can sync passwords locally and use them **offline**.  They have a free version so you can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little bit developer-centric, but with my team at work I use KeePass and Subversion.  There are a bunch of sites that offer free Subversion (or SVN as you might see it called) accounts; my favorite is [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/).

You will do well to use an SVN client as well.  The most popular one for Windows is [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), and you can use the free version of [SmartSVN](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/index.html) on a Mac.

Again, maybe a bit tech-y but will definitely do the job.

Comment: Sorry about not hyperlinking well, but there's a limit on links for newbs like me :)